Opacity not having any effect in beamer
I want to have a frame background image in beamer that has opacity. I am using the following code:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

% Define the background image and its transparency
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[opacity=0.1, at=(current page.center)] {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{vangoghwaves.tiff}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{frame}
    \BackgroundPic
    \frametitle{Your Slide Title}
    Your content goes here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

But the image opacity does not change.  I have also tried:
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.3] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{vangoghwaves.tiff}};}

in the preamble and various others, but it simply remains stubbornly opaque.
Any suggestions welcome.  I am using Texifier (which is up to date), and have also tried various different typesetting options to no avail.
Added a screenshot here:


Since when have LaTeX had support for tiff files? Does this even compile without error?

If I change your image to \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image} then it works just fine, and the is a clear difference when you change the opacity.

Unrelated: you don't need \usepackage{graphicx}, beamer already loads it.

@daleif - thank you, but it still doesn't work for me. No error for the tiff file - but I also have it as a jpg and that still doesn't work.

Please specify which engine you use (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex). Which reviewer are you using? Does it support opacity?

Can you try with \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}? This way we would see if the problem is with your picture/compilation or your viewer.

@daleif and Sam: ok - I copied your text exactly and then changed the typesetter. LuaLatex works - the others don’t, and I was using the built in version from Texifier!

How would I know which typesetters did and didn’t support opacity?

@hydrologist No idea what "typsetters" texifier has to offer. Usually any engines which directly produce a pdf, e.g. pdflatex, lualatex should work. Dvi-based tool chains, like latex, etc might have a problem with transparencies.
